# Why do I get a wedge instead of a loop when using the simple deform bend modifier?

Tags: modifiers

I am trying to bend shape a few degrees using Modifiers -> Simple Deform -> Bend. However, instead of  bending my shape into a semi-circle, this modifier keeps bending my shape into a wedge. I have tried moving the origin of my shape and rotating my shape, but I always get some sort of a wedge. I have tried slicing the shape.I have also tried changing the angle of the bend. What am I doing wrong? [image: The wedge that I am getting.]

Comment: Hello ! I assume this is the default cube ? The simple deform modifier doesn't add any geometry. Try adding a few loop cuts in edit mode along the Z axis

Comment: Did you subdivide your shape?

Comment: How do you want it to bend?

Comment: @Gorgious I added 8 loop cuts in both the x and y directions. I said slices in my question, but I meant loop cuts.

Comment: @moonboots I want it to arc slightly, like 10 degrees, along the x-axis.

Comment: If you want it to bend on X you'll need som horizontal edge loops: https://www.zupimages.net/up/23/48/c8r1.jpg also make sure that you've applied the rotation (Ctrl A)

Comment: @moonboots Thanks. Adding loop cuts around the z-axis fixed the issue. If you want to submit that answer, then I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to bend on X you'll need some horizontal edge loops:

[image]